# Octave error: undefined near line 1 column 21

Tags: runtime-error, undefined, octave

I need to define a grid that goes from zero to the maximum of the data (100 steps)
This is the command I was supposed to use:

```
zgrid = 0:zmax/100:zmax
```

In my case "z" is called "Red", so I wrote:

```
zgrid = 0:Redmax/100/Redmax
```

But it returns an error:

```
error: 'Redmax' undefined near line 1 column 20
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is a very basic question. I think you might want to read the language [documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/), or a nice tutorial first. But in any case, one does not obtain the maximum of an array by appending "max" to the variable name. There is a function called `max` for this, which you can call on your `Red` variable as follows: `max(Red)`. As for zmax, the code where you got this from probably defined `zmax` as a variable before using it here. Presumably there's a line `zmax = max(z)` somewhere in that other code.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou is definitely right, therefore please read his comment carefully. You need to initialize `Redmax` variable. He gave an idea, where you need to initialize the variable.

Comment: Thank you! I never had anything to do with coding before, let alone Octave but now I need to do a whole worksheet (it's 12 pages long) on coding until Thursday so I don't exactly have the time to read or watch a tutorial

Comment: you're going to need to understand the basics to get through that worksheet.  Octave uses the same language as Matlab, and there are a lot of great tutorials.  Here's a tutorial presentation hosted by MIT that shouldn't take too long to get you started:  http://web.mit.edu/biophysics/sbio/PDFs/R2_slides.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises whenever the Octave scripts are saved in a different path/location from the default path where all the scripts are saved. I managed to resolve it by moving all the scripts to a default location which was the Ubuntu home directory for me.